# Stored Procedure renders no data when URL is clicked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures

My web application consist of a list of URLs that retrieves information from a database when clicked. The application works well using the following non-stored procedure approach:

**code**:

```
Retrieve the connection string stored in the Web.config file.
        Dim connectionString As [String] = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbName_dbConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()

        Dim mySQLQuery As String
        Dim vID As String

        vID = Request.QueryString("submittalList")

        mySQLQuery = "SELECT submittalsInfo.CategoryID, submittalsInfo.url, submittalsInfo.headerName, submittalsInfo.FileName FROM submittals INNER JOIN submittalsInfo ON submittals.CategoryID = submittalsInfo.CategoryID WHERE (submittalsInfo.CategoryID = submittals.CategoryID) AND submittalsInfo.CategoryID = '" & vID & "' AND submittalsInfo.isActive = '1' ORDER BY submittalsInfo.FileName"

        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(mySQLQuery, connection)

        Dim myReader1 As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

        While (myReader1.Read())
            showSubHeader.Text = myReader1.GetString(2).ToString + ":"
            showurls.Text = showurls.Text + "<div>" + myReader1.GetString(1).ToString + "</div>"

        End While
        connection.Close()
```

...I'm attempting to produce the same results using a stored procedure. The following is my setup:

**Store Procedure**:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[showSubmittals]

AS
Begin
    SELECT submittalsInfo.CategoryID, submittalsInfo.url, submittalsInfo.headerName, submittalsInfo.FileName FROM submittals INNER JOIN submittalsInfo ON submittals.CategoryID = submittalsInfo.CategoryID WHERE (submittalsInfo.CategoryID = submittals.CategoryID) AND submittalsInfo.CategoryID = '" & vID & "' AND submittalsInfo.isActive = '1' ORDER BY submittalsInfo.FileName 
END
```

...and here is the code am using to call it:

```
 'Retrieve the connection string stored in the Web.config file.
    Dim connectionString As [String] = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("webname_dbConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand()
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    myCommand.CommandText = "showSubmittals"
    myCommand.Connection = connection
    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim myReader1 As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

        While (myReader1.Read())
            showSubHeader.Text = myReader1.GetString(2).ToString + ":"
            showurls.Text = showurls.Text + "<div>" + myReader1.GetString(1).ToString + "</div>"

        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        connection.Close()
        connection.Dispose()
    End Try
```

...The problem am encountering is that the page (URLs) renders no results when the URL is clicked. The following shows how my URL is setup, I'm attempting to render the results in the page showSubmittals.aspx, which contains the back-end code (my approach) I explained above :

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Accessories" NavigateUrl="~/showSubmittals.aspx?submittalList=1" CssClass="submittalsLinks" />
```

Could I please get some assistance as to how I may accomplish this task using the stored procedure approach?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the stored procedure return data when ran in SSMS?  A stored procedure from SQL server should return data just like a query.  SQL server isn't like Oracle; it doesn't need a reference cursor.

Comment: Did you try to debug and see if while loop gets executed after the command is executed?

Comment: Why your stored procedure have vb syntax of string concatenation? You need to have `vId` as parameter in your stored proc and pass it from the code.

Comment: That stored procedure wouldn't even save. Surely you're getting an error when running that `alter` command.

Comment: and since the SP isn't even saved, your all to it fails. Andbecause of that, when you look in your F12 console you'll see that the request to URL threw a 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stored proc should look as following.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[showSubmittals]
 @vid NVARCHAR (255) // Use appropriate datatype for parameter
AS
Begin
SELECT submittalsInfo.CategoryID, submittalsInfo.url, submittalsInfo.headerName, submittalsInfo.FileName FROM submittals INNER JOIN submittalsInfo ON submittals.CategoryID = submittalsInfo.CategoryID WHERE (submittalsInfo.CategoryID = submittals.CategoryID) AND submittalsInfo.CategoryID = @vid AND submittalsInfo.isActive = '1' ORDER BY submittalsInfo.FileName 
END
```

And you need to call the procedure from code as following.

```
Dim connectionString As [String] = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("webname_dbConnectionString").ConnectionString
Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

Dim vID As String

vID = Request.QueryString("submittalList")
Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand()
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
myCommand.CommandText = "showSubmittals"
myCommand.Parameters.Add ("@vid", vID)
myCommand.Connection = connection
Try
    connection.Open()
    Dim myReader1 As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

    While (myReader1.Read())
        showSubHeader.Text = myReader1.GetString(2).ToString + ":"
        showurls.Text = showurls.Text + "<div>" + myReader1.GetString(1).ToString + "</div>"
    End While
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
Finally
    connection.Close()
    connection.Dispose()
End Try
```

Pardon syntax mistakes. I am posting this answer from Mobile device.

Comment: Thank you! I greatly appreciate your help in resolving the issue.